# Custom permission not passing to generic views django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am writing custom permission and inheriting in the generic views but it is not working it returns

> TypeError: Cannot cast AnonymousUser to int. Are you trying to use it in place of User?

instead of `User required to perform this action`

my custom permission as follow

```
class IsOwnedByUser(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        message = {'detail': 'User required to perform this action'}
        return obj.user == request.user
```

**views.py**

```
class OrderAddressView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = OrderAddress.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderAddressSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnedByUser,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return OrderAddress.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

BTW, it works fine with default rest framework permission class when I use like this

`permission_class = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)`

but with my custom permission it is not working( Can anyone tell why it is that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding both (permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsOwnedByUser,)

Comment: yes if both are added it works. But it should work with one of them

Comment: @Nerd what do u mean by "It should work with one of them"? You only allowed to use one permission or what?

Comment: since the user is not logged in request.user will be Anonymous which is casusing you ths problem the user has to be logged in in order to access request.user in your case

Comment: @PavanKumarTS oh I go your point yeah you are correct Thanks

Comment: where did you override the custom permission? May be you didn't specify the location properly..

Comment: I created in authentication folder app and used in orders folder

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as Pavan Kumar told you, you should use both **(permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwnedByUser)**
But if you want to use only one permission, you can create your own:

```py
class IsAuthenticatedAndOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'User required to perform this action'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a default in your settings.py file. Try with the following (adjust the permissions as you want though as in docs):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ]
}
```